# Geocode Autocomplete example won't return result with my api key

Tags: here-api

I've generated the sample URL with my api key by clicking on the {YOUR_APIKEY} that inserts my API key into the example on [HERE Geocoder Autocomplete API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder-autocomplete/dev_guide/topics/quick-start-get-suggestions.html) documentation page. I've then entered that in the URL bar of a Chrome browser. The result is a page that says:

This site can’t be reached, autocomplete.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com refused to connect.
Search Google for autocomplete geocoder here api suggest
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Can I not just test this to see what the result is? I need to be able to submit a URL and read the JSON result for a list of addresses. These are ill-formatted addresses, so I'm looking for the autocomplete to try to find the correct address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Geocoder Autocomplete API doesn't redirect `http` requests to `https`, so just update your requests to use https:

```
https://autocomplete.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/suggest.json?apikey=<YOUR_APIKEY>&query=Pariser+1+Berl
```

Comment: You're missing `&query` in `?apikey=<YOUR_APIKEY>=Pariser+1+Berl`. But good point nonetheless, as the url on the example page should indeed be https (and http should redirect to https)

Comment: Such a simple answer. Thanks so much. Would be helpful if it was correct in their sample generation!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code in js and also js+html code that might help you >https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/rest/geocoding_suggestions

Create a Dom element which could take an input or enter it manually!